# How to extract a substring using sub and regular expression using example of street addresses in R?

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataframe with street addresses with some of the addresses with or without unit numbers. I want to extract the unit number portion into a new field.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

CivicAddress <- c("1000 FAKE STREET", "UNIT 1 1000 FAKE STREET", "UNIT 2 1000 FAKE STREET")
df2 <- data.frame(CivicAddress, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(UnitNo = sub("\\s*UNIT \\S+\\s*", "", CivicAddress))
```

I'm able to successfully match with the unit number, but I'm not sure how to phrase the expression to have it return just the unit number (e.g., UNIT 1, UNIT 2). Currently my code strips the unit number and returns the remainder of the address.

Comment: `sub("\\s*(UNIT \\S+)\\s.*|.*", "\\1", CivicAddress)`

Comment: If you're working with addresses on a regular basis, it might be worth checking out some of the r packages for working with addresses, like `censusxy` or `postmastr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `str_extract` with a regex lookaround

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
  mutate(UnitNo = str_extract(CivicAddress, "(?<=UNIT )\\d+"))
```

-output

```
             CivicAddress UnitNo
1        1000 FAKE STREET   <NA>
2 UNIT 1 1000 FAKE STREET      1
3 UNIT 2 1000 FAKE STREET      2
```

If we need the 'UNIT' substring as well

```
df2 %>%
   mutate(UnitNo = str_extract(CivicAddress, "UNIT \\d+"))
```

-output

```
              CivicAddress UnitNo
1        1000 FAKE STREET   <NA>
2 UNIT 1 1000 FAKE STREET UNIT 1
3 UNIT 2 1000 FAKE STREET UNIT 2
```